# Create login with groups (with roles) and users with revoke roles - Symfony2

Tags: authentication, symfony, doctrine-orm

I there,
I Want create a custom authentication that provides user roles, groups and roles groups. The login that i want to create is the next:

Users have groups and groups have roles;

Users have roles. This roles is for to revoke roles from groups.

ie:

```
Groups:
    Group1: ROLE_WRITE, ROLE_READ
    Group2: ROLE_CHECK, ROLE_NEW
Users:
    Groups:
        Group1
        Group2
    Roles
        ROLE_CHECK
```

With above example the user can only use 3 roles ROLE_WRITE, ROLE_READ and ROLE_NEW

I made the following classes

Roles.php

```
namespace Test\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface;


/**
 * Test\OverSkyBundle\Entity\Roles
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="roles")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */

class Roles implements RoleInterface{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=70, unique=true)
     */
    private $role;

    public function __construct( $role )
    {
        $this->role = $role;
    }

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getRole(){
        return $this->role;
    }
    public function setRole($role){
        $this->role = $role;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->role;
    } 
}
```

Groups.php

```
namespace Test\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Test\OverSkyBundle\Entity\Groups
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="groups")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */

class Groups {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=70, unique=true)
     */
    private $groupname;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Roles")
     *
     */
    private $roles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->groupname;
    } 

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles->toArray();
    }
    public function setRoles($roles)
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;
    }
}
```

Users.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/** 
* Test\OverSkyBundle\Entity\Users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Test\UserBundle\Entity\UsersRepository")
 */

class Users implements UserInterface, \Serializable{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Roles")
     *
     */
    private $roles;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Groups")
     *
     */
    private $groups;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=140)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=140, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive; 

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    } 

    public function __construct() {
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles->toArray();
    }
    public function setRoles($roles)
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;
    }

    public function getGroups()
    {
        return $this->groups->toArray();
    }
    public function setGroups($groups)
    {
        $this->groups = $groups;
    }    

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }    

    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }
    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }    
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        return $this;
    }  

    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }  
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;
        return $this;
    }   

    public function eraseCredentials() {

    }

    public function serialize() {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
        ));        
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        list (
            $this->id,
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

index.html.twig

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ZAP') %}
    dasdsa
{% endif %}

{% for groups in app.user.groups %}    
    <li> groups </li>
{% endfor %}
```

**In twig file i can access to user roles but not the groups roles. How can i merge both and revoke with the roles present in users?**

If i try to execute for groups in app.user.groups.roles,I receive an  error that roles is not found.

When execute if is_granted, i recieve the user roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is_granted()` calls the user's **getRoles()** method and checks wether the given argument role is inside the returned array of roles. ( simplified - the security provider calls getRoles and adds them to the security-context then is_granted checks the security-context to be more precise )

Now if you want to return the roles inherited from the user's groups you will have to merge those.

Though i don't know why you're trying to **revoke** the user's roles from those provided by the groups ...

( normally user's roles **extend** their group-provided roles - if you don't want certain roles, don't add the user to the group )

... you can do something like this:

<kbd>Users.php</kbd>

```
public function getRoles()
{
    $groupRoles = array();
    // add all roles provided by groups
    foreach ($this->getGroups() as $group) {
        foreach ($group->getRoles() as $role) {
            $groupRoles[] = $role;
        }
    }
    // - remove dublicates
    // - revoke user's roles
    // - return remaining roles
    return array_unique(array_diff($groupRoles, $this->getRoles()));
}
```

Comment: thank you. Helped me a lot. Finally  i found the solution!

- "normally user's roles extend their group-provided roles - if you don't want certain roles, don't add the user to the group" - 

Yes, you're right but in this situation we need this solution because we want groups like moderators, adimns .. . Groups have pré-roles, certain users are parte of certain groups but don't have certain roles of that group.